# JDBC/PLSQL: How can I get a return value of a anonymous block

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I have an anonymous code-block.

```
String plsql = "DECLARE\n";
plsql += "\tret NUMBER;\n";
plsql += "\tretsum NUMBER := 0;\n";
plsql += "BEGIN\n";
plsql += "\tret := 1;\n";
plsql += "\tretsum := ret + retsum;\n";
plsql += "END;\n";
```

I call it by JDBC.

```
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall (plsql);
boolean ret = cs.execute ();
cs.close ();
```

All if working so far.

How can I make my anonymous block to return a value (e.g. retsum) into my Java-code?

I am aware of stored functions and to handle the return there - but I can not do that here.

```
CallableStatement cst = con.prepareCall ("{? = call foo ();}");
cst.registerOutParameter (1, Types.INTEGER);
cst.execute ();
int ret = cst.getInt (1);
```

Comment: The anonymous blocks in PLSQL are like Vegas: what happened in the block stays in the block. You need to convert it to a function in order to return values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a bind variable (either `?`, for an anonymous variable, or `:something`, for a named variable) in the anonymous block:

```java
String plsql = "DECLARE
  ret NUMBER;
  retsum NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  ret := 1;
  retsum := ret + retsum;
  ? := retsum;
END;";

CallableStatement cst = con.prepareCall (plsql);
cst.registerOutParameter (1, Types.INTEGER);
cst.execute ();
int ret = cst.getInt (1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way available since Oracle 12c is to declare inline function and use general `select` statement:

> ```
> with function f
> return number
> as
>   ret NUMBER;
>   retsum NUMBER := 0;
> BEGIN
>   ret := 1;
>   retsum := ret + retsum;
>   return retsum;
> END;
>
> select f() as res
> from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | RES |
> | --: |
> |   1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0bc4b184980ed567d4a533a27592d946)*